# Is there an option to replace output of PsExec error code with another output?

Tags: powershell, psexec, powershell-5.0

I'm running a code that waits for WinSCP Process to run and then waits for it to close automatically.

Now I'm trying to replace the regular output of psexec:

```
cmd exited on <Host> with error code 0
```

With the output,

```
WinSCP has been downloaded the files successfully.
```

Some code that I'm using Psexec with:

```
psexec \\<Host> -u <User> -p <Password> powershell Wait-Process WinSCP
```

I've tried to throw any of the output commands using the

`| Out-Null` and still it doesn't work

Comment: So you just want to modify the output on psexec? What do you mean by "throw any of the output commands using `Out-Null`"?

Comment: I meant that I'd like to overwrite the output of normal psexec with the argument ```psexec \\<Host> -u <User> -p <Password> powershell Wait-Process WinSCP | Out-Null ```.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to capture the response and check the error codes of the it.

```bsh
$response = & psexec \\<Host> -u <User> -p <Password> powershell Wait-Process WinSCP

switch -regex ($response) {
    'error code 0' { $output = "WinSCP has been downloaded the files successfully." }
    'error code 1' { $output = "Something else"
    # Add other error codes from your application
    default { $output = "Unknown error" }
}

return $output
```

Comment: I will try that approach and update with findings, Thanks.

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work .. I'm getting always default output and not the error code 0 one ...

Comment: You would need to capture and check `$response` is actually matching the values in the switch when writing your own code block. If `$response -match "somestring"` does not equal true, you will always hit the default output.